# How to connect to an SSH server running on a Windows 10 machine

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I know that this question may have been answered somewhere, but I'm a total noob about this subject and couldn`t follow up on any tutorial. So any help would be appreciated :)

Here's the thing: I can access a computer at the university lab via ssh from home using the command `ssh user@universityIp -p 1234` for example. But I can't connect from the university computer to my home machine via ssh.

I already found out that my internet provider blocks port 22, but they told me that they could enable another port superior to 1024. So I asked them to enable port 5678 (for example), even though I had no idea how it could help me. Also, I have already changed the port on the sshd_config file to 5678.

Knowing that my home machine is a Windows 10 running OpenSSHServer, how can I connect from the university computer to my home machine using ssh? Suppose that my public IP is 111.111.11.11 and my intranet IP is 192.168.250.250. Also, is there another thing that I have to change in my sshd_config file?

Sorry if I'm being repetitive, but I have no idea about what I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP 111.111.11.11 is the public IP of your home router.
You need to

- open port 5678 on your home router and
- enable port forwarding for port 5678 to your internal IP address 192.168.250.250

Then you should be able to connect from your university to your home computer's OpenSSH server running at port 5678 (as you mentioned you already did).

Comment: I believe that steps 1 and 2 are already done by my internet provider, but I'm getting the `Connection closed by remote host` error. Just to check, if everything is working, I should type `ssh myUser@publicIP -p 5678` to connect to my home machine right?

Comment: Why do you believe that steps 1 and 2 have already be done by your provider? Opening port 5678, and also enabling the port forwarding,  has to be done by YOU - in your router preferences. However, the command `ssh myUser@publicIP -p 5678` is correct.

Comment: I searched the options of my router everywhere and I couldn't find the option to open the port and enable port forwarding. So I called my internet provider and they told me that I'm not allowed to change the configurations by myself, but they could do it for me. That's why I believe they already did, even though I don't know if it is possible to check it.

Comment: That sounds really horrible :-/ Your internet provider should forward _ALL PORTS_ to your endpoint/IPaddress and _ONLY YOU_ should decide which ports are forwarded to wherever.... Are you in some kind of institution? Because if you can't do it on your router, you're probably out of luck...

Comment: No, I'm at home. The problem is my internet provider. I already saw some complaints about them on the internet from people with the same problem. I just thought that after contacting them I should be able to solve it by myself. I just need to send some files from the university lab to my computer :/ Anyway, thanks for your help.